# Convert Spark DF to a DS with different fields names

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pojo, apache-spark-dataset

I want to convert a Spark dataframe to a dataset of a POJO with different fields names. I have a dataframe of the fields: `name`, `date_of_birth`, where their types are `StringType`, `DateType`.

And a POJO of:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private Date dateOfBirth;
}
```

I *convert it to dataset successfully* with the following code:

```
Encoder<Person> personEncoder =  Encoders.bean(Person.class); 
Dataset<Person> personDS = result.as(personEncoder);
List<Person> personList = personDS.collectAsList();
```

Only if I change the dataframe’s columns names before that, to those of the Person POJO. Is there any way of telling Spark to map between the fields from the POJO side?

I thought about Gson’s `@SerializedName(“date_of_birth”)` but it didn’t affect anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a name mapping, say in a Map, you could use it to rename the columns before converting the dataframe into a dataset.

It could be written like this:

```java
// I create the map, but it could be read from a config file for instance
Map<String, String> nameMapping = new java.util.HashMap<>();
nameMapping.put("id", "name");
nameMapping.put("date", "dateOfBirth");

Column[] renamedColumns = nameMapping
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(x -> col(x.getKey()).alias(x.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .toArray(new Column[0]);

result.select(renamedColumns).as(personEncoder)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of specific annotations. However, here is how I'd solve it.

I would create a specific dataframe with the shape I want, then export it.

It would look like:

```
Dataset<Row> exportDf = df
    .withColumn("dateOfBirth",
        col("date_of_birth").cast(DataTypes.StringType))
    .drop("date_of_birth");
```

The full example I wrote can be found here: https://github.com/jgperrin/net.jgp.labs.spark/tree/master/src/main/java/net/jgp/labs/spark/l999_scrapbook/l002.

Notes:

- I am assuming that `result` in your code is a `Dataset<Row>`.
- I used String for your date as Spark was a little touchy about converting a Date to a String in a POJO. If you need help specifically on this issue, create another SO question, I'll happily look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! This solution doesn’t quite fit because I want the conversion to be dynamic so I would be able to add a column and a field for the DF and the POJO, and it will work without touching the conversion code.

Comment: I get it... be careful about datatypes though, they might trick you in the conversion... especially dates!